# Observer Pattern (temperature, pressure and humidity)

Tags: java

I need you help in my observer pattern where I'm suppose to update when either TEMPERATURE or PRESSURE or HUMIDITY is updated. Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TemperatureSensor t = new TemperatureSensor();
    PressureSensor p = new PressureSensor();
    HumiditySensor h = new HumiditySensor();
    WeatherObserver w = new WeatherObserver();
    w.addSubject(t);
    w.addSubject(p);
    w.addSubject(h);
    t.setTemperature(28);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    p.setPressure(200);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    h.setHumidity(89);
}

class Subject {
    private List<Observer> observers=new ArrayList<Observer>();
    public void attachObserver(Observer observer) {
    this.observers.add(observer);
    }
    public void detachObserver(Observer observer) {
    this.observers.remove(observer);
    }
    public void notifyObservers() {
    for (Observer observer: this.observers)
            observer.update(this);
    }
}

class TemperatureSensor extends Subject {
    private double temperature;
    public double getTemperature() { return this.temperature; }    
    public void setTemperature(double temp) {
    this.temperature=temp;         
       this.notifyObservers();  // don't forget to do this!
    }
}

class PressureSensor extends Subject {
    private double pressure;
    public double getPressure() { return this.pressure; }    
    public void setPressure(double press) {
    this.pressure=press;         
    this.notifyObservers();  // don't forget to do this!
    }
}

class HumiditySensor extends Subject {
    private double humidity;
    public double getHumidity() { return this.humidity; }    
    public void setHumidity(double humid) {
    this.humidity=humid;         
        this.notifyObservers();  // don't forget to do this!
    }
}

abstract class Observer {
    public Observer(Subject subject) {
    subject.attachObserver(this);
    }
    abstract public void update(Subject subject);
}

class WeatherObserver extends Observer {
    public WeatherObserver(Subject subject) {
    super(subject);
    }

    public void addSubject(Subject subject){
        subject.attachObserver(this);
    }

    public void update(Subject subject) {
        TemperatureSensor temp=(TemperatureSensor)subject;        
        System.out.println("Temperature: " + temp.getTemperature() + " Celcius");
        /*PressureSensor press=(PressureSensor)subject;
        System.out.println("the temp is: " + press.getPressure() + " Pascal");
        HumiditySensor humid=(HumiditySensor)subject;
        System.out.println("the temp is: " + humid.getHumidity());*/
    }    
}
```

How do I update the pressure and humidity at the end in the update method? Is there anyway to cast multiple subjects? Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to know what kind of object are you receiving in update method, to do that you can use the keyword instanceof.

```
class WeatherObserver extends Observer {
   public WeatherObserver(Subject subject) {
      super(subject);
   }

   public void addSubject(Subject subject){
      subject.attachObserver(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void update(Subject subject) {
      if (subject instaceof TemperatureSensor){
          TemperatureSensor temp=(TemperatureSensor)subject;        
          System.out.println("Temperature: " + temp.getTemperature() + " Celcius");
      } else if (subject instaceof PressureSensor ){
          PressureSensor press=(PressureSensor)subject;
          // use press
      } else if (subject instaceof HumiditySensor ){
          HumiditySensor humid=(HumiditySensor)subject;
          // use humid
      } else {
          throw new ClassCastExeption("Unexpected instance of Subject: " + subject.getClass());
      }
    }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are making new list of observer is subject, which should be common to all.
Thats the mistake.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
    TemperatureSensor t = new TemperatureSensor(observers);
    PressureSensor p = new PressureSensor(observers);
    HumiditySensor h = new HumiditySensor(observers);
    WeatherObserver w = new WeatherObserver();
    w.addSubject(t);
    w.addSubject(p);
    w.addSubject(h);
    t.setTemperature(28);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    p.setPressure(200);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    h.setHumidity(89);
}

class Subject {
protected List<Observer> observers;

public Subject(List<Observer> observers) {
    this.observers = observers; // you need common observer so that you can
                                // receive callback
}

public void attachObserver(Observer observer) {
    this.observers.add(observer);
}

public void detachObserver(Observer observer) {
    this.observers.remove(observer);
}

public void notifyObservers() {
    for (Observer observer : this.observers)
        observer.update(this);
}
}

class TemperatureSensor extends Subject {

public TemperatureSensor(List<Observer> observers) {
    super(observers);
}
private double temperature;

public double getTemperature() {
    return this.temperature;
}

public void setTemperature(double temp) {
    this.temperature = temp;
    this.notifyObservers(); // don't forget to do this!
}
}

class PressureSensor extends Subject {
public PressureSensor(List<Observer> observers) {
    super(observers);
}
private double pressure;

public double getPressure() {
    return this.pressure;
}

public void setPressure(double press) {
    this.pressure = press;
    this.notifyObservers(); // don't forget to do this!
}
}

class HumiditySensor extends Subject {

public HumiditySensor(List<Observer> observers) {
    super(observers);
}
private double humidity;

public double getHumidity() {
    return this.humidity;
}

public void setHumidity(double humid) {
    this.humidity = humid;
    this.notifyObservers(); // don't forget to do this!
}
}

abstract class Observer {
// public Observer(Subject subject) {
// subject.attachObserver(this);
// }

abstract public void update(Subject subject);
}

class WeatherObserver extends Observer {
// public WeatherObserver(Subject subject) {
// super(subject);
// }

public void addSubject(Subject subject) {
    subject.attachObserver(this);
}

public void update(Subject subject) {
    System.out.println("updated");
    // TemperatureSensor temp = (TemperatureSensor) subject;
    // System.out.println("Temperature: " + temp.getTemperature() + " Celcius");
    /*
     * PressureSensor press=(PressureSensor)subject;
     * System.out.println("the temp is: " + press.getPressure() +
     * " Pascal"); HumiditySensor humid=(HumiditySensor)subject;
     * System.out.println("the temp is: " + humid.getHumidity());
     */
}
}
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Is there a way to do it without changing anything from the class Subject and Observer?

Comment: I dont think you can achieved this without changing your source code. Your mistake is you are creating new arraylist in subject class. After you update temperature or pressure, the new arraylist got updated . To solve make the common observer list which will get callback on update.

Comment: Try running the code , there's minor modification. This is the easiest way you can achieve what you want. If you have some other objective then do let me know. In the update method you can check the type of class by using "instanceof" eg if(subject instanceof temperature) //then do something.

Comment: your welcome. One suggestion -> If you think you have received the answer you must close the question by placing a tick on the answer.